# Unable to transfer twilio call to new number

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

We have small twilio application which we use to calls any customer number from website. Now we are trying to add transfer call functionality in our application. 
But we are unable to transfer call using php api.
Here is what we are using :

- We dial number from website, JS returns callid
- We have another number on which we need to transfer call after few minutes
- So we have "Transfer" button which makes ajax call to php file

which have following code :

```
<?php
    $existing_call_sid = $_REQUEST['CallSid'];
    $new_number = $_REQUEST['new_number'];
    $call = $client->calls($existing_call_sid)->update(
                array(
                    "url" => "transfer_xml_main.php?new_number=".$new_number,
                    "method" => "POST"
                )
            );
    echo $call->to;
?>
```

transfer_xml_main.php contains :

```
<Response>
    <Dial><?php echo $_GET['new_number'];?></Dial>
    <Say>Please be on line we are transferring your call</Say>
</Response>
```

- But when this request happens existing call is dropping and no call to new number.
- also $call->to is blank

Am i doing anything wrong?

**Update**

After implementing answer of philnash i am getting following fatal error :

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to update record: No 'To' number is specified' in /twilo/twillo_php_master_new/Twilio/Version.php:85
Stack trace:
#0 /twilo/twillo_php_master_new/Twilio/Version.php(127): Twilio\Version-&gt;exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to updat...')
#1 /twilo/twillo_php_master_new/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/CallContext.php(109): Twilio\Version-&gt;update('POST', '/Accounts/AC618...', Array, Array)
#2 /twilo/twilo_call_transfer.php(26): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\CallContext-&gt;update(Array)
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>/twilo/twillo_php_master_new/Twilio/Version.php</b> on line <b>85</b><br />
```

However i am getting parent call id correctly and in $child_calls i am getting to and from correctly which is one who called first and one whom user is called. Still anything wrong ?

And yes we want exactly like you said : 
1. User1 (agent) called one number (customer A) from twilio JS Client
2. Now User1 (agent) want to transfer call to another number which can be agent or some other number.

Also there is no errors in debugger

Comment: Can you send me a CallSid for a call on which this happened? You can email it to philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: Thanks! Sent you an email.

Comment: I have an idea. How are you sending the `new_number` that you are forwarding the call? Can you share that JS?

Comment: Sure, mailed you JS.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm surprised that no call is happening. Are there any errors in your [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

I can see some issues though.

The CallSid you get from the JS when you dial out is the Sid of the dialling leg, the one owned by your agent. But, I'm guessing you want to transfer the person that is called to a new number. If that is the case then you need to get the Sid of the receiving leg of the call. The dialling Sid is the parent Sid for the calls, so you can look up the other leg by [listing child legs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters), like this:

```
<?php
    $parent_call_sid = $_REQUEST['CallSid'];
    $child_calls = $this->client->calls->read(array("ParentCallSid" => $parent_call_sid));
    $child_call_sid = $childCalls[0]->sid;
    $new_number = $_REQUEST['new_number'];
    $call = $client->calls($child_call_sid)->update(
        array(
            "url" => "transfer_xml_main.php?new_number=".$new_number,
            "method" => "POST"
        )
    );
    echo $call->to;
?>
```

Secondly, your [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) you return is the wrong way round. If you want the message to come before you start dialling, then you need to put the [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) first.

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please be on line we are transferring your call</Say>
    <Dial><?php echo $_GET['new_number'];?></Dial>
</Response>
```

When you do all of this, your original dialler will get cut off as the call is transferred. You may want this, though you may find that a warm transfer is a better experience. There is a good tutorial on how to perform a [warm transfer using PHP and Laravel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/warm-transfer/php/laravel) which might help.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @philinash  
thank you for your answer. I tried code as you said. but i am getting fatal error. I have updated question for error and other things. any thing still wrong ?

Comment: This doesn't work. There is no (longer?) a call sid created for the callee/receiving party. There's a call sid only for the initiator/caller.

Comment: Hey @BrianH, I see you've asked your own question so I will comment over there to try to get this fixed for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you use the POST method, but in your XML you use $_GET. You're not passing the variables.

```
<?php
    $parent_call_sid = $_REQUEST['CallSid'];
    $child_calls = $this->client->calls->read(array("ParentCallSid" => $parent_call_sid));
    $child_call_sid = $childCalls[0]->sid;
    $new_number = $_REQUEST['new_number'];
    $call = $client->calls($child_call_sid)->update(
        array(
            "url" => "transfer_xml_main.php?new_number=".$new_number,
            "method" => "POST" // <---NOTICE THE POST
        )
    );
    echo $call->to;
?>
```

Change $_GET to $_POST

```
<Response>
    <Dial><?php echo $_POST['new_number'];?></Dial>
    <Say>Please be on line we are transferring your call</Say>
</Response>
```